# como recibir valores continuamente de un formulario a otro en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

estoy intentando crear un enlace **(a)** entre 2 formularios, bueno el principal es de tipo MDI (primer formulario) asi que en el segundo formulario tengo un DataGridView y cuando selecciono una fila, he creado una variable que coge su valor e inmediatamente con un boton hago que me muestre la variable en el formulario 3, bueno dejo unas imagenes de referencia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en el **FRM_Nuevo** (2)

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
Try
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim selecionar_columna As DataGridViewRow
        i = e.RowIndex
        selecionar_columna = DataGridView1.Rows(i)
        a = selecionar_columna.Cells(0).Value     'variable enlace (a)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'no pasa nada
    End Try
End Sub
```

En el **Frm_Editar** (3)

```
Public Class Frm_Editar
 Public a As Integer
 Private Sub Frm_Editar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label.Text = a 'esto funciona solo al iniciar el formulario
    End Sub
End Class
```

Quisiera que al hacer click en el DataGridView1 y con el formulario 3 abierto, cambie el texto del Label, ¿se puede hacer?, necesito su ayuda y si hay algo que no ha entendido sobre mi pregunta, no dude en hacermelo saber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

En tu evento `DataGridView1_CellClick` escribe esto:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer

    If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        Frm_Editar.Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, también estaba pensando en lo mismo